# Trying to close an app and replace a file but I get an error on the file

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process lsharp = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Noo\Desktop\Documents\loader.exe");
    Process myProcess = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Noo\Desktop\Music\VoliBot.exe");
    Process F5 = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Noo\Desktop\F5.exe");

    if(myProcess.HasExited == true)
    {
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("VoliBot");

        if (pname.Length == 0)
            F5.Kill();

        File.Copy(@"C:\Users\Noo\Desktop\game.cfg", @"C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\Config\game.cfg", true);
        Console.WriteLine("The Config was replaced.");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The error is: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\Config\game.cfg' is denied.

Comment: Doesn't the error message give you enough information already?

Comment: I want to know how to solve it...

Comment: You have an authorization issue hence the exception. It tells you what the problem is: the account under which the application is run has not the proper rights to the mentioned folder. If you just want access to this folder then this is not a programming issue, it is a security setting issue.

Answer (score 1):

Some process is still keeping your file locked or you genuinely do not have access to it. You can use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see who has a handle on your file. In the top menu look for a subitem "Find file/handle" or something along those lines.
Also, I think you need to pass VoliBot.exe to GetProcessesByName instead of VoliBot. 
And I am presuming you are Noo and not trying to access another user's home directories.

Comment: I am pretty much sure I am not trying to access another user's home directions since I am only using 1 user. Could you  by chance help me with the Process Explorer, I am new to coding

Comment: Try [this](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/processlock.htm) to find who's still keeping your file (game.cfg).

Comment: It found no results :\

Comment: Presuming you checked with process explorer at the at the proper time and no later, then maybe it is a permissions issue. Try to access the file without the process manipulation bits from your code. Leave just the file copy, run it, and see what happens.